# Does it have to be the same thermistor?

Tags: thermistor

I have two blown thermistors in a TV. I can't get the same part locally in the UK and ordering it from China will take a month at least so im looking for an alternative from local electronics parts store like RSComponents.

Part is: TKS SCK08102MSY otherwise goes by SCK-102

Relay is [HF162F 12-H](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/660183/HONGFA/HF162F/12-H.html)

When selecting an alternative, I found [this one here,](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/thermistor-ics/1857867) but its specs are a bit different in the datasheet. It has the same ohms at 25C and 2A rated but wattage is lower, etc.

Any ideas on what I need as an alternative or does it have to be that exact same component?

Oddly, the TV still works. It powers on fine but it doesn't power off. When the remote power button is pressed, the TV goes into standby for a few seconds then tries to power back on and keeps cycling off and on unless I press the power button on the remote while it is in the off cycle, then it powers on and stays on.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

added some pics of TDK thermistor datasheet, can these be used or is it risky?
[image]

[image]

[image]

this is fixed now, replaced the 2 thermistors and now the tv turns off and stays off. powers on and stays on too so its a win. thanks everyone

Comment: Normally, seeking for product recommendation is off-topic here, hence the two close votes. But this question, `does it have to be that exact same component?`, makes it less off-topic, so I won't vote. Anyway. Assuming you reverse-engineered it, where are those NTCs used *(The datasheet says "for inrush limiting" which allows me assume that they are on mains input or rectified DC/bulk but who knows)*? Do you see anything that potentially shorts them (relay, SCR, etc) because if they are inrush limiters then they are supposed to be shorted after turn on, to decrease the power consumption. ...

Comment: ... Relays and SCRs are the most common ways to short them. If there's a relay or SCR then I don't think they have to be the same part as they are inrush limiters only, and they operate for a fraction of a second (or for a few seconds) which is usually short enough time for them to survive.

Comment: yes you are correct those 2 thermistors were next to a relay

Comment: Oh weird, the first photo is with the relay removed actually, isn't it?

Comment: yes i removed the relay to test it and its working fine thats when i was able to confirm the markings on the thermistors. there is one more thermistor on the board next to another same type of relay and that one is fine not popped yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about exact replacement: inrush NTCs are a very undifferentiated product family. Same size and rating will do.  Yes, that looks like a usable substitute.

As for what nuked them, that's impressive damage; I wonder if something shorted elsewhere, perhaps momentarily so it's still working, but long enough to damage these parts.

That would seem to suggest they're always-on, not bypassed with a relay.  But perhaps the relay itself has malfunctioned.

There is a relay pictured, but it's not obvious if it's a power on/off function, or a thermistor bypass, or what.  Reverse engineering and component testing is needed to determine the full extent of things to replace.

Comment: thanks for the reply, iv just updated the main post with a pic of the back of the board, Red boxes are the thermistors and blue boxes are the legs of the relay. i find it very odd that when the tv is on it works fine no issues for hours on end but its just wont turn off? can thermistors cause a tv to not turn off? usually its a turning on issue iv seen.

Comment: Yeah. It seems something bad happened here, but it seems likely there are more things out of place elsewhere.

Comment: I agree, going up slightly in NTC size isn't a big deal for 99 % of applications out there, but perhaps worth mentioning that there is an upper limit if the thermal mass is so large it does not heat up enough in time before the (timed) relay closes. Ask me how I know...

Comment: Any idea on what thermistors i can replace these ones with? They look like they are running in series. The main fuse on the board is 6.3a which did not blow. Iv checked the bridge rectifiers and mosfets for shorts with multimeter but no issues found there. I suspected i would not find something else since tv still powers on and works.

Comment: would it be a case that any 10ohm 2amp NTC thermistor would do the job?

Comment: @slybunda And same size, say give or take 20% diameter.

Comment: ahh ok, original disc was around 8.3mm in diameter so replacement need to be physically similar in size as specs?

Comment: The blown thermistors have resistance of 38.5ohms and 226kohms tested with multimeter the working one has a resistance of 14.2ohms (its around 16c in my room temp wise) putting my finger on the working thermistor makes its ohms start to drop down. iv also added pics of a TDK thermistor and specs from its datasheet. can this be used to do the job?

Comment: iv replaced the 2 thermistors and the tv is working properly now. there is a 3rd thermistor on the board near another relay, its working properly but do you guys think i should replace it too?

Comment: I have no idea. Enjoy the TV!

Comment: replaced the working one anyways. knowing my luck it would probably pop next week. it does have a bit higher resistance than the new ones when tested once removed from board.